# how to set the size for multidimensional array in php

Tags: php

how can I use  SplFixedArray to set the size for a multidimensional array? 
or is there any other methods I can use to predefine the size of the array

Comment: Array sizes in PHP are always defined by the content, so there is no way to "predefine the size". This seems like an XY problem. What is the underlying goal?

Comment: Not needed, but `$array = array_fill(0, 10, array_fill(0, 5, null));`

Answer (score 0):

simple - from usual array

`$a = SplFixedArray::fromArray(array(1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3));`

http://php.net/manual/en/splfixedarray.fromarray.php

Answer (score 0):

I found this so far:

```
$sub = new SplFixedArray(2);
$sub[0] = '0';
$sub[1] = '1';

$arr = new SplFixedArray(2);
$arr[0] = $sub;
$arr[1] = $sub;

print_r( $arr );
```

**Output:**

```
SplFixedArray Object
(
    [0] => SplFixedArray Object
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => SplFixedArray Object
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
        )

)
```

**Further:**

```
$arr[0][0] = '00'; // Working
$arr[0][1] = '01'; // Working
$arr[0][2] = '02'; // Error: Caught exception: Index invalid or out of range
```

**Problem found:** (All sub arrays are changed when changing one sub array)

```
$arr[0][0] = 'a';
$arr[0][1] = 'b';

print_r( $arr );
```

**Output:**

```
SplFixedArray Object
(
    [0] => SplFixedArray Object
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => SplFixedArray Object
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

)
```

**Work around:**

```
$sub1 = new SplFixedArray(2);
$sub1[0] = '0';
$sub1[1] = '1';

$sub2 = new SplFixedArray(2);
$sub2[0] = '0';
$sub2[1] = '1';

$arr = new SplFixedArray(2);
$arr[0] = $sub1;
$arr[1] = $sub2;

$arr[0][0] = 'a';
$arr[0][1] = 'b';
$arr[1][0] = 'c';
$arr[1][1] = 'd';

print_r( $arr );
```

**Output:**

```
SplFixedArray Object
(
    [0] => SplFixedArray Object
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
        )

    [1] => SplFixedArray Object
        (
            [0] => c
            [1] => d
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

SplFixedArray alone is **not** meant to be multi-dimensional and it doesn't work if you try.
See the following code trying to initialize an 8x8 matrix:

```
 $a = new SplFixedArray(64);
 for($i=0;$i<8;$i++)
     for($j=0;$j<8;$j++)
       $a[$i][$j] = $i*$j;
```

It doesn't throw error in PHP7.4, but it **doesn't work** either. If we dump $a, we will see that it is full of NULL values. 
A 2D PHP array is array of arrays, so let's check if this works:

```
$a = new SplFixedArray(8);
$a = array_fill(0, 7, array_fill(0, 7, new SplFixedArray(8)));
for($i=0;$i<8;$i++)
     for($j=0;$j<8;$j++)
       $a[$i][$j] = $i*$j;
echo $a[7][7]; // prints 49
```

It is working now. But let check if it has SplFixedArray:

```
var_dump($a);
```

prints:

```
 array(8) {
  [0]=>array(8) {
....
```

**Nope !!!** Completely overriden by the standard PHP array, so better we hadn't had initialized it.
I know you want a single faster N-Dim array, but SPL doesn't have it. I think it easily can be implemented by the guys working on SPL if such feature gets requested. But for now, you can use only the standard PHP array. If you use SplFixedArray::fromArray() on a 2D PHP array, you'll end up with one SplFixedArray of standard PHP 1-d Arays. But ASAP you write something using double index e.g. `$a[2][2]=4;`, you'll get an error:

```
PHP Notice:  Indirect modification of overloaded element of SplFixedArray has no effect
```

The answer of Naveed shows you that it can be done this way:

```
$a = new SplFixedArray(8);
foreach($a as $k=>$v)
    $a[$k] = new SplFixedArray(8);
```

In a loop we create SplFixedArray of SplFixedArray structure. While this works, beware that using it is ~30% slower in PHP7.4 than using the standard PHP array. But if you need huge array still you might save some memory.